# ssis lookup transformation for very large table

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I have two tables Person & Ownership having one to many relationship (each person have many ownerships). Primary Key is person_id of type GUID. I am developing SSIS package to load data from both tables to destination. In destination tables, I want to  add surrogate key so that in future my sql joins use surrogate key not the GUID (Because GUID is slow). I did following tasks

- in destination table I created person table with one additional column person_id_sk of type bigint (identity column).
- load data to person
- similarly created Ownership table with one additional column person_id_sk of bigint
- load data to person with "lookup transformation".

The process in very slow as there are millions of record in both table and the package needs to be run twice in a week.

Is this the only way to insert surrogate key values in parent child relationship? or there are any other efficient way.

regards,

Comment: What you also can do is instead of using Lookup, try using Merge. This can speed up your total runtime, because it will start loading two tables simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL operation would almost certainly be faster than the SSIS one.  Load the Person data in SSIS, with the database engine creating the IDENTITY surrogate key.   Leave the GUID in so that it goes to the table.  Load the Ownership data in SSIS, but don't do anything about the surrogate key at this stage.

Then update the child rows FK in an SQL operation like this:

```
UPDATE o
SET person_id_sk=p.person_id_sk
FROM
Ownership o
INNER JOIN
Person p
ON o.GUID=p.GUID
```